# how can I add a grey border to the CKeditor 4 plugin?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, editor

I am using the CKeditor 4 with (Microsoft 2013) styling version. I am trying to add a grey padding to give the user the same user experience of using the normal word file like what is attached in the below image.

Should I add a certain style or there is an additional script that should be added?
[word example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XwAE.png)

Comment: Style the container element you put the editor in

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to change the editor color try this in the header under the `JS` of the `CK`

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.uiColor = '#c5cdc8';

    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        ...
    ];

    config.removeButtons = 'Save,NewPage,Form,Checkbox,Radio,TextField,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,Flash,Language,About';

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding a listener for the maximize option that will add padding to the container when its maximized to make it look like a word document.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpd1v.png)

```js
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (evt) {
        (evt.editor.on('maximize', function (evt) {
            console.log(evt.editor.getCommand('maximize').state)
            if (evt.editor.getCommand('maximize').state == 1) {//ckeck if maximize is off
                style = document.getElementById("cke_1_contents").style.cssText
                document.getElementById("cke_1_contents").style.cssText = style + "padding-left: 180px;padding-right: 180px;padding-top: 25px;padding-bottom: 25px;"
            }
        }))
    })
```